# How to set a field with out creating an object in java

Tags: java, json, multithreading

I can't modify either Class A or Class B. And both Class A & B are huge in size (with several nested Classes and hundreds of parameters). And with multiple threads, memory foot print is impacting the performance.I'm checking all ways to reduce memory usage. Basically I'm trying to limit the scope of Class B instance so that GC can work on it at the earliest. 
(For Your Information: I already knew that I can do by B b = new B(); b.setS("Calm Down"); a.setB(b);)

Here is the scenario:

```
Class A{
private B b;
public getB{return b}
public void setB (B b){this.b = b;}
}

Class B{
private String s;
//getters and setters for s}

Class MyNeed{
A a = new A();

// Here I'm trying to create an obj B and set S and then pass that obj to a.setB().
a.setB (new B().setS("Param S Set")); 
}
```

So I guess that new B() is local to setB(). so in the very next line new B() is out of scope.

But this way in eclipse, I'm getting error that setB() can't accept void. I guess it is setS() returning void.

May be I'm missing some concepts. But I want to have something such simple. How to implement this.

Comment: public B setB (B b){this.b = b; return this;}
} Sorry. I missed the return type. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have a **constructor** within the class A:

```
class A{
    private B b;
    public B getB(){
        return b;
    }
    public void setB (B b){
        this.b = b;}
    }
    public A(S s){
       this.S = s;
    }
}
```

So when you do `a.setB()`, you can just do `a.setB(s)` and that will set the object S for that A object.

Comment: I don't have any access to either Class A or Class B. And Class B is huge. And with multiple threads doing the mapping, memory foot print is impacting the performance.

Answer (score 0):

> `a.setB (new B().setS("Param S Set"));`

Ok, That statement starts by creating a new B instance, then it calls the `setS` method on that instance, passing it the string `"Param S Set"`.  Finally, it calls `a.setB(...)` passing the value returned by the setS() call.

As you already know, that doesn't work because setS() returns `void`.

> May be I'm missing some concepts. But I want to have something such simple. How to implement this.

```
{
    B b = new B();
    b.setS("Param S Set");
    a.setB(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is wrong. setS() does not return B instance.
You will not save any resources by writing one-liners. 
GC will also not clean anything if you set B to A as long as A has a reference to B.

Answer (score 0):

I got it using builder design pattern. Thanks to @Builder by lombok.

Thank you all.